# How to speed up Javascript development in Eclipse and JSPs?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsp

in my everyday coding I work on J2EE projects where I deal with Javascript in JSP pages in Eclipse. I find it very annoying that every time I modify some JS code in a JSP or in a .js file, it takes a very long time to have it updated on the server. I've been a JS coder for a while and one of the things I enjoyed is the easyness of editing code, it just takes a page reload if you work on a static page. Anyway sometimes I cannot take this approach and I need to have the code working inside the JSP. So I was wondering if there is a way to speed this up... One of the things I noticed is that updates to JSP take a small amount of time when the project is small and they take more and more as the project size grows. How do I speed it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this kind of problem, one of my general strategies or future goals is to get more into test-driven development.

I think I must learn how to cleverly [mock](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) things in my data storage layer, so that there is no database i/o or file i/o.

In a similar way, many resource-intensive parts in the business logic layer can be mocked. If you had isolated the tiers properly, you can develop JS and test locally.

Comment: This is true, but sometimes it's very hard to do, especially with legacy code. I was wondering if there is some trick or shortcut to speed up the process.